# How can I get who I am sending a message to?

Tags: macos, applescript, message

I'm trying to write an applescript which  will append 'xxx' to the end of the message if I am sending it to my SO. Obviously I don't want to add 'xxx' on every message I send.

I've tried recipient, myBuddy and a few others that I've lost track of and none of them work.

my code is below:

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message sent theMessage for theChat
        // if recipient is THE MRS
        set kisses to " xxx"
        set myResponse to theMessage & kisses
        return myResponse
    end message sent
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

The on message sent event handler only returns the text of the message and a description (and type of message).
None of these contains the recipient, so you can not get who the message is being sent to.  The best you can accomplish is text substitution, say, if you wanted any occurrence of xxx to substitute in for something else.

Remember you can set up text string autocomplete system-wide in System Preferences/Keyboard, to accomplish similar things.